# formato de las fechas al exportar de java a excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

hola estoy exportando a excel un jtable. Y me exporta bien todos los datos excepto las fechas. Al final de la funcion `public void exportToExcel` se hacen una serie de `else if` con unas conversiones, pero me faltan las de las fechas. Este es el codigo:

```
public void exportToExcel(JTable table, String filePath) throws Exception {
  TableModel model = table.getModel();
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Row row;
  Cell cell;

  // write the column headers
  row = sheet.createRow(0);
  for (int c = 0; c < model.getColumnCount(); c++) {
   cell = row.createCell(c);
   cell.setCellValue(model.getColumnName(c));
  }

  // write the data rows
  for (int r = 0; r < model.getRowCount(); r++) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r+1);
   for (int c = 0; c < model.getColumnCount(); c++) {
    cell = row.createCell(c);
    Object value = model.getValueAt(r, c);
    if (value instanceof String) 
    {
     cell.setCellValue((String)value);
    } 
    else if (value instanceof Double) 
    {
     cell.setCellValue((Double)value);
    }
    else if (value instanceof Integer)
    {
     cell.setCellValue((Integer)value);
    }
    else if (value instanceof Long)
    {
     cell.setCellValue((Long)value);
    }
    else if (value instanceof BigDecimal)
    {       
     cell.setCellValue(((BigDecimal) value).doubleValue());
    }
    else if (value instanceof BigInteger)
    {       
     cell.setCellValue(((BigInteger) value).longValue());
    }
   }
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  //workbook.close();

 }
```

Comment: estás usando docx4j?

Comment: estoy utilizando poi, la herramienta de apache para java para exportar a excel.

Comment: listo, agregué la etiqueta a la pregunta para que obtengas más ayuda